# Apache2 mod_mono ubuntu virtual hosting

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, apache-http-server, mono-framework

I am new so I hope y'all can help. I setup a development machine that I want to use for development ( a laptop with ubuntu 12.04 for .NET/mono/asp.netmvc development and php/laravel development). I compiled the latest mono from source and when I do a mono -V I get 3.2.7.
I installed apache using tasksel and installing lamp. I build my web applications and test using xsp and it works fine. When I try to host the same app in apache it only shows me the files & folders but doesn't serve up the pages for me. I am using virtual hosting this is my test application virtualhost file before doing an a2ensite:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@testasp
ServerName testasp
ServerAlias testasp

DocumentRoot /var/www/testasp/public_html

MonoServerPath testasp "/usr/local/bin/mod-mono-server4
MonoDebug testasp true
MonoSetEnv testasp MONO_IOMAP=all
MonoAutoApplication disabled
MonoApplications testasp "/:/var/www/testasp/public_html"

<Location "/">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    MonoSetServerAlias testasp
    SetHandler mono
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
</Location>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Now I am stumped cos I am not sure what I am missing or what configuration settings I have wrong. And just to be sure, I have enabled and included mod_mono.conf in apache2.conf file. Been doing a lot of googling and have seen that php and mono don't play nice. If that is the case does it mean I have to use one or the other? Hope y'all can help me fix this.

Thanks and God bless.

As a Note, I want to reinstall my ubuntu and install a newer version of it and try everything again and see if I its the os or not. I read somewhere that if you have mod_php and mod_mono on ubuntu server it just doesn't work as apache will not know to serve cshtml pages with mod_mono. You would have to disable mod_php. I dunno if this is true but will try this before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the apache log file and see what the error is and search for solution on it.

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

In my case, I have installed mono and mod_mono from source. They work on apache with PHP working on it. Here is a link that will help you get started:

http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/run-asp-net-mvc-4-with-mysql-on-linux/